# TeamCity - How to run Nunit step on 'client' machine which isn't a build agent

Tags: nunit, teamcity

The issue I'm currently facing is that I don't want the tests to be ran on the build agent as it increased load on the VM the agent is installed on, and I have a dedicated VM for automation

My current build step looks like this

[image: TeamCity Nunit Step]

%TestDirectory% is a parameter which points to my network share - for example \[vm-name]\testfiles$\

At the moment I'm getting the following error when trying to run the tests

[image: TeamCity Test Result]

I've tried adding the network path to
Control panel -> internet options -> security -> intranet -> sites -> advanced -> new site

I've also tried adding

```
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
<loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
```

To nunit-console.exe.config & nunit-console-x86.exe.config, but nothing so far is changing this error

Any advice / help would be great

Comment: If you have a dedicated VM for automation, then you should install your agent there...

Comment: Hello - I only have 3 agents which are all currently being used - so installing an agent on the machine isn't an option